# Deploying a contract gives the error : Unable to connect to socket: timeout

Tags: mist

I pasted this example contract : https://www.ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code
in Mist (ubuntu 16)

And I got the not so helpful error messages :

```
Could not compile source code 
Error: Unable to connect to socket: timeout"
```

I have connected to the TEST-NET

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just closed the application and restarted it. It works now.

P.S. Make sure you have the latest build

Answer (score 0):

Check the RPC_URL that you are using. It might be wrong.
Check this [website](https://chainlist.org/)

Choose your network for e.g. sepolia, mumbai matic,
You'll get a rpc_url.
Use it in your code.